# Does facebook trigger an event when user of an app makes an update?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook app development and trying to make an application using servlets.
I want to keep an eye on users updates with the help of my app.
Does graph apis send any trigger or event to my app server when somebody post anything or we have to keep polling FB to get latest updates? I am asking this because we may run some data analytics to process FB data. For that we may have to store data we get from FB to our local database to run analytics tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Real Time updates API to get this

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: Yeah I got this.. I am taking my words back... :)